# Twilio c# helper, How do I use this method signature? void AddOutgoingCallerId (phoneNumber, friendlyName, callDelay, callback)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twilio

I'm trying to follow the Twilio docs for adding a Caller ID as a verified out going telephone number.

The Twilio c# helper library has a method signature which looks like so

void AddOutgoingCallerId (phoneNumber, friendlyName, callDelay, callback)

where callback is `Action<ValidationRequestResult>`

I don't understand this. I'm trying to set a URL that Twilio can post back to once the verification has taken place.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement a method that takes a `ValidationRequestResult` and returns `void`. That's the method that will get called. You provide that method as the callback parameter.

Here's your call:

```
AddOutgoingCallerId (phoneNumber, friendlyName, callDelay, HandleAddOutgoingCallerId)
```

And here's the method that you need to create.

```
private void HandleAddOutgoingCallerId(ValidationRequestResult result)
{
    // Do something (or just return).
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you help.  I get a red squiggly line saying "The best overloaded method match for Twilio.TwlioRestClient.AddOutGoingCallerID(string,string,int,string, System.Action<Twilio.ValidationRequestResult>) has some invalid arguments.

Comment: That's five parameters. In your question, you show four. I would need to see how your calling the method with the five parameters.

Comment: See if that works. `HandleAddOutgoingCallerId()` needs to take a `ValidationRequestResult`, not an `Action<ValidationRequestResult>`.